# Browse remote machine files in Nautilus

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, ssh, nautilus

I'm running old Debian machine:

```
Distributor ID: Debian 
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.2 (lenny) 
Release: 5.0.2 Codename: lenny
```

And I'm using Nautilus file browser in it:

[image]

I'm missing "Connect to server" feature that exists on my new Ubuntu Nautilus:
[image]

How to connect to other machine via SSH using old Nautilus file browser?

UPD

I did File->Connect to server

Got menu:
[image]

I have entered params and start waiting forever. When I have restarted Nautilus I got new item near `Network Servers` and Nautilus is still trying to connect without success.

[image]

I can SSH to current machine without problem using console. What is `Nautilus` is waiting for?

Comment: Debian 5 is long [unsupported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Debian_releases#Release_table). You should update to something more recent and more secure.

Comment: if the option's not there you may need to do it by hand, mount the server using sshfs.. or perhaps use filezilla instead.